# How do I increase value of a column variable in postgresql when I select row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with simple columns - name, gender, age, etc. And I have a column named view_count.
By default, it's 0. I need to increase this value on +1 every time when a row is selected.

I need a query something like this:

```
Select name, age from table_name Limit 1, view_count+=1
```

Comment: You will most likely have to make a function to handle the select and update for you, for other operations you could make a TRIGGER, but this is not an option for SELECT

Comment: So I probably need to use update anyway, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an UPDATE and return the data as it was an SELECT:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET view_count = view_count + 1
WHERE ? = ? -- some condition or not?
RETURNING name, age; -- proces this like a SELECT statement
```